# What should be the steps to be followed before working on a multistore website?

Tags: magento-1, multistore, best-practice

I am going to work on a Magento multistore website.
The site is already live , I need to setup a development environment and need to work on this development site.

What should be the steps which I should follow before starting to work this kind of setup?
Apart from checking the categories, are these different for all the stores? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the following things:

- Do the different websites use different templates and if so do they share parts of their templates
- Do they use the same category root or does each website have their own root
- Do they use the same products and if so do they share prices or are their differences in pricing
- Check which modules are installed and whether these are activated for each website

Then for your local setup, you should create an Apache VirtualHost for each website, so you can access them e.g. under http://local.website1.de and http://local.website2.de

One option for this is to put your store under /var/www/store and have a switch statement in your index.php which decides based on your URL which website to serve.